# event.item.valueField showing undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, amcharts

I am using AMCharts and I'm trying to call another function on clickGraphItem event with parameters.

The parameters and their values that I need are:

**Year**: 2017 (which is my category in the graph)

**Gender**: Men/Women (which is available in title or valueField. So getting an output from either of them works for me.)

On using event.item.category I do get my desired output but the event.item.valueField and event.item.title gives me undefined. I even tried using all other options but the output I get is undefined. Please suggest a way I can get the output I am looking for?

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartYearlydiv", {
                        "type": "serial",
                        "theme": "light",
                        "legend": {
                            "horizontalGap": 10,
                            "maxColumns": 1,
                            "position": "right",
                            "useGraphSettings": true,
                            "markerSize": 10
                        },
                        "dataProvider": chartYearlyData,
                        "valueAxes": [{
                            "stackType": "3d",
                            "position": "left",
                            //"axisAlpha": 0.3,
                            //"gridAlpha": 0
                        }],
                        "graphs": [{
                            "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
                            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                            "labelText": "[[value]]",
                            "lineAlpha": 0.3,
                            "title": "Men",
                            "type": "column",
                            "color": "#000000",
                            "valueField": "Men"
                        }, {
                            "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
                            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                            "labelText": "[[value]]",
                            "lineAlpha": 0.3,
                            "title": "Women",
                            "type": "column",
                            "color": "#000000",
                            "valueField": "Women"
                        }],
                        "categoryField": "Year",
                        "plotAreaFillAlphas": 0.1,
                        "depth3D": 60,
                        "angle": 30,
                        "categoryAxis": {
                            "gridPosition": "start",
                            "axisAlpha": 0,
                            "gridAlpha": 0,
                            "position": "left"
                        },
                        "listeners": [{
                            "event": "clickGraphItem",
                            "method": function (event) {
                                alert(event.item.category + event.item.title);
                                LoadMonthly(event.item.category);
                            }
                        }],
                        "export": {
                            "enabled": true
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value in the event by using `event.item.values.value`. See the docs for [`graphDataItem`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/GraphDataItem) which is the object you're pulling your category from in the [`clickGraphItem` event](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#clickGraphItem) as the `values` property contains that and more. The `clickGraphItem` event also gives you access to the [`graph` object](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph) the item belongs to, allowing you to pull the `title` property directly from it through `event.graph.title`.